# Sales order grid not loading for restricted roles in magento2

Tags: magento2, user-roles, resources

I have created a new resource with limited access for only dashboard and sales.

**System >> User Roles**

then created the new user and assigned the above Role.

If i login with the new user which is created recently.

I can access all the resource set for the particular user in admin.

But When i navigate to Sales > Orders

Grid is not loading where i have several orders in the database.

This shows when i login with admin user.

I have made a research on this. Someone suggested to disable asynchronous indexing. But that is already disabled in my case.

I am getting one javascript console error like below.

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null
```

This is a strange issue, Can anyone look into this and update me Please.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: @SohelRana, its 2.2.6

Comment: @SohelRana, Is there any patches available for this issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce in fresh installation

Comment: @SohelRana, I have checked by disabling the installed modules but no luck